# Overriding MacOS Device Configuration at runtime

Tags: macos, system-profile

Currently we enable bunch of configuration scripts to end users (Mac) through device profile management. However we want to provide users to opt-out of them temporarily (with sudo access).

Is it possible to override those settings dynamically using `system_profiler`?
What are the options for it.